# nuxt i18n not working in IE throwing SCRIPT1006: Expected ')'

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, internet-explorer-11, nuxt-i18n

I am trying to make the nuxt-i18n work for IE document mode 11.

SCRIPT1006: Expected ')'

Comment: Keep in mind that IE11 is out of support since months, and a lot of packages already removed support for it

Comment: Thanks Nico for response but we are using old application so need to add support.

Comment: see: https://caniuse.com/?search=Default%20parameters

Comment: actually I added polyfills to support es6 features.